# SQL Server 2012 Service Broker dialog security

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am new to service broker and I am setting up a distributed topology. Two physical servers in the same domain, to replace a hacked up two way replication that continues to cause data corruption.

I am using the same domain account for both ends of the conversation and I am getting "The certificate's private key cannot be found" in profiler.

I had the same setup working with two separate local logins previously, so I am thinking that my issue is the fact that I am now attempting to use the same user account on both ends.

So my question is, does service broker require separate user accounts on each end of the conversation if I am using domain account with windows authentication, and if so is there any real advantage to using domain accounts instead of the way I had it previously with two local logins.

Comment: How is the broker endpoint configured for authentication? If it's set up to use certificates, you have to have the same certificate (with both the public and private key) available on both servers in master.

Comment: From my understanding of the documentation I could find on Service Broker, when the two databases exist on separate physical servers, you are forced to use dialog security. Which from all I can deduce from the documentation, only uses certificates. I was unable to find any documentation stating that you can do dialog security using only windows domain authentication. I have copied the cert that was created on each endpoint to the other endpoint and attached it to the user account, the same domain user on each endpoint.